Reversing JSON api output to ascending order by date
I am currently facing a problem with the FinancialModelingPrep api. For purposes of charting, I need the api output to sort on an ascending basis, but the response comes back in descending order.
The output is as follows:
[
  {
    "date": "2023-09-08 15:55:00",
    "open": 178,
    "low": 177.99,
    "high": 178.34,
    "close": 178.19,
    "volume": 2640606
  },
  {
    "date": "2023-09-08 15:50:00",
    "open": 177.93,
    "low": 177.79,
    "high": 178,
    "close": 177.995,
    "volume": 1188267
  },
  {
    "date": "2023-09-08 15:45:00",
    "open": 178.01,
    "low": 177.9,
    "high": 178.14,
    "close": 177.925,
    "volume": 757194
  }...
]

I have tried using different params in the url such as revert=true, but have had no luck in solving it, and there is zero guidance from FMP on how to do so.

Array.prototype.toReversed()

Since the output is an array, you can use it's sort method to sort the array based on the timestamps of each individual element in every order you want, let's say you have named the output data to the output variable, use the code below:
output.sort((a, b) => new Date(a["date"]) - new Date(b["date"])); // Ascending

output.sort((a, b) => new Date(a["date"]) + new Date(b["date"])); // Descending

Just sort it after you have the response, and I guess it will solve your problem.
